# How to compare the distributions of variables within clusters?

Tags: distributions, clustering, data-visualization, data-mining, k-means

I used K-means to cluster 15k data points composed of 5 quantitative features scaled between 0 and 1.
I would like to compare the distributions of the features within each cluster, and also compare them with the distributions of the entire dataset, if it makes sense.

1. What kind of **quantitative approach** can be used?
2. What kind of **visual aid** can be used? (histograms, box-plot, ...)

Here is an example of what I did for the entire dataset (features not normalized yet):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try superimposed histograms, one histogram for each cluster, coloured differently.

Numerically, you can try a rank-sum test and report the $p$-value.

Answer (score 1):

Stacked bar charts and scatterplots are an obvious choice.

Note that your heuristic scaling has a massive impact onto your result; the findings may not be statistically well supported, but just one of many possible results.

Comment: I thought that learning algorithms perform better with features with the same scale. Can you explain further, please?

Comment: They work better when features have a comparable scale, so 1 unit should have the same importance each. Squeezing everything to [0;1] does not mean everything is adequately weighted. It's just a crude heuristic that often is somewhat better than not scaling at all.